# Discover on what inherited class it points

Tags: java, inheritance

I have one base class BASE and couple inherited class BASE_1, BASE_2,, BASE_3. I have in code BASE test but how to discover on what class it points: BASE_1, BASE_2 or BASE_3 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BASE test = getSomeBase();

// method 1
System.out.println(test.getClass().getName());  // prints the classname

// method 2
if (test instanceof BASE_1) {
   // test is a an instance of BASE_1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not clear what you are asking but you can make use of `getClass()`  method and `instanceof` operator.

If it is something like

```
Base b = new Child1();
b.getClass();//will give you child1
```

Answer (score 3):

To see the class name of a particular object, you can use:

```
test.getClass().getName();
```

But you shouldn't generally care, since any functionality that depends on which subclass you have should be implemented as overridden ("polymorphic") functions in those subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `instanceof` to check for a specific type or `.getClass()` to get a `Class` object describing the specific class:

```
Base test = getSomeBaseObject();

System.out.println("test is a " + test.getClass().getName());
if (test instanceof Base1) {
  System.out.println("test is a Base1");
}
```